# Missing references after fresh install of system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I reinstall my whole system, visual studio, and packages (control suite, crystal reports and so on), and download my solution from team foundation. When I try to rebuild it, I get missing references warning and it does not work :

[image: missing references]

When I check, all nugets package are (physically) here. The thing which annoys me the more is that even System, System.Data,... are in warning state. Anybody already had this problem (and a fix !) ?

I have a lot of project in my solution, and there's only a part of them which screw up (sorry for my english, it is not my native language).

Comment: did you try to eliminate all the usual suspects when dealing with broken references? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se.aspx

Comment: judging from the fact that system packages appear to be missing, is your project targeting a .NET version that is installed on your machine?

Comment: also, is this .NET or .NET core?

Comment: It is .net 4, It worked well on my older install with same settings, thanks for your link, I try that now.

Comment: make sure you check all the projects in your solution if they are targeting old (or newer) versions

Comment: Checked all but not better now :(

Comment: Please try to (1) install .net framework 4.0. (2)delete the packages folder. (3) restart the Visual Studio (4) reopen the project, change the target framework to 4.0. (5) Execute the command line `Update-Package –reinstall
`in the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a fix which was to copy all files from my previous disk which were not in TFS and it fixed it all. I am a bit ashamed because I skipped to list them to add util files in TFS. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, nuget package restore.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding them manually under **Solution Explorer**->**right-click your project node** then-> click **Properties**. Click on the **References tab** and re-add them to the project.

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se.aspx for more suggested solutions. Hope this helps